# Running Apache.Ignite.exe in version 2.13 throws System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: .net, exception, ignite

I was going to upgrade Apache Ignite from version 2.10 to 2.13. When I am running Apache.Ignite.exe from apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461 with default config file, I am getting the exception bellow. Is that a bug in 2.13 version?

ERROR: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for igniteConfiguration: Type 'Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'. (C:\Program Files\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461\Apache.Ignite.exe.Config line 23) ---> System.TypeLoadException: Type 'Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'.
at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.VerifyAssignableType(Type baseType, Type type, Boolean throwOnError)
at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at Apache.Ignite.Config.Configurator.ReadConfigurationSection(Tuple`2[] args) at Apache.Ignite.Config.Configurator.GetConfiguration(Tuple`2[] args)
at Apache.Ignite.IgniteRunner.Main(String[] args)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. Filed it: [IGNITE-16958](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16958).

As a workaround, use .NET Core binaries: `dotnet platforms\dotnet\bin\Apache.Ignite.Executable.dll`

Comment: Can you tell when 2.14 will be released?

Comment: @StasShvarzman there is no date yet, my guess is mid-autumn.

Comment: Any chance to get a dll with fix based on 2.13? We are going to release new version of our application in October so we cant wait so long. We have to upgrade Ignite becase of log4j issues.

Comment: I can build and publish an unofficial pre-release nuget package from master, will that work for you?

Comment: I can't use the pre-release package but if I can just replace exe or dlls in bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461 in 2.13 with the ones from your build, the yes it will work!

Comment: If you want to keep jar files and only replace exe/dlls, building from master won't work. You can check out ignite-2.13 branch, cherry-pick the fix and build .NET binaries only.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to do what you suggesting. If you can build full pre-release will it include files from bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461? I just want to replace .Net binaries in that specifc folder.
I dont know if it is possible but the best solution for us will be of course to build only the exe/dll with the IGNITE-16958 fix on 2.13 branch.

Comment: I've created a branch from 2.13 with cherry-picked fix here: https://github.com/ptupitsyn/ignite/tree/ignite-2.13-16958. Clone it, then in `modules/platforms/dotnet` run `./build.ps1 -skipJava`, you'll get release binaries in `bin`.

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel! I will try that and update.

Comment: I upgraded successfully from 2.10 to 2.13 using the executables from the branch you created. Thank you very much for help. The only issue that I encountered is that in release  douments of 12,3 is said that it supports JDK 17. When I tried to upgrade from JDK 11 to 17 I am getting the following exception when running Apache.Ignite.exe. Is that another bug?

Comment: C:\Program Files\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461>"C:\Program Files\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461\Apache.Ignite.exe"
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option --illegal-access=permit; support was removed in 17.0

Comment: ERROR: Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Java exception occurred [class=java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, message=] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.memory.PlatformAbstractMemory.<clinit>(PlatformAbstractMemory.java:27)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.init(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:65)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.address field is unavailable.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1567)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1554)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.bufferAddressOffset(GridUnsafe.java:1554)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.<clinit>(GridUnsafe.java:109)
        ... 3 more

Comment: You don't need to upgrade to JDK 17. Support was added, but it does not mean that JDK 11 is no longer supported. Personally I'm on 11, have not tried 17 yet.

Comment: From what I understand from our security officer JDK 11 has some known vulnerabilities. We will probably need to upgrade it in the near future. Is that a bug that I am getting this exception with JDK 17?